# Using Retrofit / GSON how can I handle responses that are sometimes empty and other times not

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am using retrofit with GSON. The web service I am connecting to will at times return an empty payload to the client. I didn't build it this way. The problem is that this causes a json parse exception when GSON tries to parse the empty payload. How could I handle this? Is there a way to make the callback have an null model object?

So for example the server response might be "" or it might be:

```
{
"foo":{"id":"123","description":"abcd"}
}
```

I also have in java:

```
@Data // This comes from lombok to generate setter,getter,no args constructor...
public class Foo{
 private int id;
 private String description;
}
```

My retrofit service looks like this:

```
public interface MyService{
 @POST("/poorly/designed/api/foo")
 void getFoo(@Header("Authorization") String auth, Callback<Foo> callback);
}
```

Disclamer: I just typed up the most simple example I could so forgive me if I wrote something that might not be exactly syntactically correct. You get the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit should generally just null out any missing values. The problem with your code is that the server returns an object with a `Foo` inside rather than just a `Foo`. Try adding another class

```
class FooContainer {
    Foo foo;
}
```

and then have your API call return a `FooContainer` instead of a `Foo`.

Comment: Your right. It will return null for the response object if the response is completely empty. I feel embarrassed asking.

Comment: I think in the past it was throwing an error on what I thought was an empty payload but was probably just not valid json so I assumed I had to do something special to get it to work with an empty payload.